# Fujitsu Siemens V6535 laptop doesn't wake up - crash when going into standby?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, crash, power-management, standby

I'm having trouble with my laptop (Fujitsu Siemens model V6535).  It runs Windows 7, and after I upgraded from Vista I've noticed something that makes me really angry.

When my laptop goes into Standby, the power LED changes to red and starts blinking (standby mode).  When I push the power button to wake it up it, the blinking LED changes to green but nothing else happens. Nothing on the display, no HDD sound.  When I press the power button for a few seconds and then try turn it on again, it doesn't display anything.

I have to unplug the charger, shut it off, and power it on again without the power cable.  Then it starts working.

A few days ago I upgraded the BIOS to the newest version, but it doesn't help.

Does anyone have any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: Install the latest updates for Windows, as this problem was fixed by a patch.